# Move XML child element up without changing text flow

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

I have xml files which look like:

```
<a>
  <s> blah blah </s>
  <s> bleep  
      <t> something different </t> 
      bloop</s>
  <s> bleh bleh </s>
</a>
```

and would like to move the `<t>` elements up one level, **without changing the text flow** : in other words I want it to look like

```
<a>
  <s> blah blah </s>
  <s> bleep </s> 
  <t> something different </t> 
  <s> bloop</s>
  <s> bleh bleh </s>
</a>
```

I am using java with jdom2, and there must surely be a straightforward method for this, but I can't find it. Any elegant ideas? Thanks!

Comment: wow, nobody? I guess it must be because java and xml are such rare, unusual technologies... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I ended up doing it inelegantly by hand, for posterity:

```
List<Element> lstChildren = new ArrayList<Element>(eltA.getChildren());
for (Element eltS : lstChildren) {

    //find s
    if (eltS.getName().contentEquals("s")) {

        int indexS = eltA.indexOf(eltS);
        List<Element> lstSub = new ArrayList<Element>(eltS.getChildren());
        for (Element eltT : lstSub) {

            //find t
            if (eltT.getName().contentEquals("t")) {

                //split the text at the child:
                int index = eltS.indexOf(eltT);

                if (index < eltS.getText().length()) {
                    Element elt1 = eltS.clone();
                    Element elt2 = eltS.clone();

                    for (int i = index; i < eltS.getContentSize(); i++) {
                        elt1.removeContent(index);                                                        
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
                        elt2.removeContent(0);                                                        
                    }

                    eltA.removeContent(indexS);
                    eltA.addContent(indexS, elt1);
                    eltA.addContent(indexS + 1, elt2);
                }

                //move it up one level
                eltT.detach();
                eltA.addContent(indexS + 1, eltT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```